# CoreData for storing dates recommended practices

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, core-data, swift

I'm making a simple shift tracker / salary calculator to practice CoreData and Swift. I'm having issues with the different tasks related to this, as I need to use the dates to:

- Display them
- Check amount of shifts in a week to see if you deserve extra pay (Norwegian rules gives you 5/10$+ extra per hour if you work more than 12 hours that week)
- Add all salaries in a month together
- Delete data if the user types in wrong

And probably more i'm forgetting.

As of right now, I'm getting the data from date pickers which use a date formatter to add them to by DB as 'fromDate' and 'toDate' as a string. This leads to me having to use a bunch of bad code. Much because of NSDate timezone issues etc.

How should I lay out my data base to do this most effectively? Should I make a field for each type of data I need? ('fromMinute'|'fromHour'|'fromDay'|'fromWeek'|'fromMonth'|'fromYear') and then corresponding for 'to' fields? I'm a rookie at databases but I don't think I should have that many fields. Should I have a month table, then a week table, then use relations (and in that case how do I do that?)

I can not just use a Time Interval, because bonuses are dependent on how late it is.

Hope someone can help me out with some recommended practices on CoreData

---

UPDATE:

Here is my super complex core data model! 
[image]

along with a NSManagedObject class ( I think )

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Shifts)

class Shifts: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var fromDate : String
    @NSManaged var toDate : String

    func getShift () -> Shift{
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd w W HH:mm"
        let from:NSDate = formatter.dateFromString(self.fromDate)!
        let to:NSDate = formatter.dateFromString(self.toDate)!
        let length:Double = to.timeIntervalSinceDate(from) as Double / 60

        let newShift = Shift(from:from,to:to,length:length)
        return newShift
    }


}
```

Shit is a class I have in my view controller which I use to display etc my data, it looks like this (TW:Code Gore)

```
class Shift {
var fromDate : NSDate
var toDate : NSDate
var length : Double //In Minutes
var salary : Double = Double()
var UB : Bool = false

let etter18hverdag:Double = 22
let etter21hverdag:Double = 45
let helligdag:Double = 90
let helgEtter13:Double = 45
let helgEtter16:Double = 90 //HUSK AT PAUSE FINNES


init (from : NSDate, to : NSDate, length:Double){
    self.fromDate = from
    self.toDate = to
    self.length = length
}
func calcSalary(ub: Bool)->Double{

    let userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let hour: Double = userDefaults.doubleForKey("salary")

    println("Checking salary on shift fromDate:\(fromDate) with length:\(length). Shift UB: \(UB)")

    if (ub){
        let calendar : NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
        calendar.locale = NSLocale.systemLocale()
        calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

        var checkTime:NSDate = fromDate
        var checkToTime:NSDate = toDate

        var totalSalary:Double = Double()

        while (checkToTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(checkTime)>0.0){

            let split = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.WeekdayCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.HourCalendarUnit, fromDate: checkTime)

            println("Checking: \(checkTime) to: \(checkToTime) diff:\(checkToTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(checkTime)) currentSal: \(totalSalary) splitTime:\(split.hour)")
            if(split.weekday==7){ //Søndag
                let lønn = hour + helligdag
                totalSalary += (lønn/4)
            }

            else if (split.weekday == 6){ //Lørdag
                if(split.hour < 13){
                    let lønn = hour
                    totalSalary += (lønn/4)
                }
                if (split.hour>13 && split.hour<16){
                    let lønn = hour + helgEtter13
                    totalSalary += (lønn/4)

                }
                if (split.hour > 16){
                    let lønn = hour + helgEtter16
                    totalSalary += (lønn/4)
                }

            }

            else if (split.weekday < 6){ //Hverdag
                if(split.hour < 18){
                    let lønn = hour
                    totalSalary += (lønn/4)

                }
                if (split.hour>18 && split.hour<21){
                    let lønn = hour + etter18hverdag
                    totalSalary += (lønn/4)

                }
                if (split.hour > 21){
                    let lønn = hour + etter21hverdag
                    totalSalary += (lønn/4)
                }
            }


            checkTime = checkTime.dateByAddingTimeInterval(15*60) //15 min ganger 60 sek i min
        }
        println("Calculated salary WITH UB: \(totalSalary)")

        return totalSalary
    } else {
        let calendar : NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
        calendar.locale = NSLocale.systemLocale()
        calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

        var checkTime:NSDate = fromDate
        var totalSalary:Double = Double()
        let multiple = (length/60)

        while (self.toDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(checkTime)>0.0){

            let lønn = hour
            totalSalary +=  (lønn/4)

            checkTime = checkTime.dateByAddingTimeInterval(15*60) //15 min ganger 60 sek i min
        }
        println("Calculated salary WITHOUT UB: \(totalSalary)")
        return totalSalary
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use unix timestamps? Easy to store and easy to calculate with.

Comment: @Oscar Apeland: Your question is not clear enough for me. I don't even know what your Core Data Model looks like. What are you Entities, what are their attributes and relationships? They will help us understand your needs for your NSDate attributes...

Comment: @POB I updated my question a little bit, have a look. And also, as far as I've seen, its not possible to store NSData in coredata?

Comment: @Apfelsaft Apple Juice :D Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The Short Version

The best practice is to store `fromDate` and `toDate` as `NSDate`s.

### The Long Version

#### What's in a date?

An `NSDate` is actually an `NSTimeInterval` since a reference date. The `NSTimeInterval` value represents the number of seconds since that date, and is irregardless of time zone, calendar, or any other geographical or political construct. Conceptually, this is the same as a unix time stamp, though unix time stamps use a different reference date (equivalent to `timeIntervalSince1970`). An NSDate represents a point in time - days, years, time zones, and daylight savings are all *presentation level* concerns, while NSDate is just a value object. It's the honey badger of date representations. It don't care.

That said, displaying an `NSDate` involves many other components, most having to do with localization. The user's localization settings determine which calendar representation (`NSCalendar`) is used, and how dates are formatted visually (`NSDateFormatter`). The user can even change these settings while your application is running, which is why there are some system notications to inform your application that there has been a change.

Performing date calculations using `NSCalendar` is not too difficult once you understand the above concepts well, and last year `NSCalendar` was extended to be even easier to use (unfortunately, those improvements only came to iOS very recently). Apple has a good guide to calendar calculations in the [Date and Time Programming Guide: Performing Calendar Calculations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1), and a session from last year's WWDC, [WWDC 2013: Solutions to Common Date and Time Challenges](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/#227), details the improvements to `NSCalendar` and covers some very good tips for working with dates in general.

If your data model stores dates as `NSDate` it is much easier to adapt the visual presentation of date values correctly for the user's localization settings. The model doesn't need to be aware of time zones, calendars, and localization settings - those are best handled at the presentation (view or view controller) level.

If you were storing dates as strings, as date components, or as calendar components you would run into a lot of issues. For example, if the current calendar changed, all of your persisted data would be invalid and would need to be rebuilt. Daylight savings time could also be a big problem.

#### How does this affect Core Data?

In your case you are representing a date range in your model (the range of seconds from `fromDate` to `toDate`). There are some alternate ways of representing the same thing, like using `fromDate` and a `duration` indicating a `NSTimeInterval` from `fromDate` to whenever the shift ended. Either approach works.

When querying data for a particular hour, first you would perform the necessary calendary calculations to get the start and end of the hour in the user's current locale.

For example, in objective-c, using the new `NSCalendar` methods:

```
NSCalendar  *calendar   = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDate      *startOfDay = [calendar startOfDayForDate:fromDate];
NSDate      *startOfHour= [calendar dateByAddingUnit:kCFCalendarUnitHour value:8 options:NSCalendarMatchStrictly];
NSDate      *endOfHour  = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:kCFCalendarUnitHour value:9 options:NSCalendarMatchStrictly];
```

This would give you the start and end of the 8th hour of the day on which `fromDate` falls. This is just an example, your business rules may dictate more logic such as checking the value of toDate against fromDate, etc. - though many of those concerns may be best handled by customizing [Core Data validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdValidation.html).

Using this in a predicate is a set of straightforward numeric comparisons:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.fromDate <= %@ AND SELF.fromDate >= %@", endOfHour, startOfHour];
```

When using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to display sections, the `sectionNameKeyPath` can point to a Core Data transient property to allow you to display sections based on hour, month, etc. as you like. Sorting and grouping query results cannot use a transient property, only a property backed by a modelled attribute - in your case, `fromDate` and `toDate`. Since dates are numeric and represent a point in time this works easily for many business rules.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, I think it answered all my problems.

Comment: Nice and very comprehensive answer +1 for it!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to store your dates like date object. The date object contains all data you need to retrieve fragments of the date. 
Then you can extend your core data object with categories to retrieve its fragment. Add some methods like -(NSInteger)year, -(NSInteger)month.
Refer to NSCalendar and NSDateComponents on how to get fragments of dates. It also helps you to add and perform manipulation on dates.